# Batch set MP4 create date metadata from filename

Tags: linux, video, file-metadata, exif

On a Linux system,
I have a bunch of MP4 files named like `20190228_155905.mp4` but with no metadata. I've previously had a similar problem with some jpg's which I solved manually with

```
exiv2 -M"set Exif.Photo.DateTimeOriginal 2018:09:18 20:11:04" 20180918_201104.jpg
```

but as far as I can see, the `DateTimeOriginal` is only for images, not videos. Videos that do have metadata have a `Xmp.video.MediaCreateDate` field that seems like what I want. I guess it contains a Unix timestamp, so I'd need a way to get the date from the filename, convert it to a Unix timestamp and set that value to `Xmp.video.MediaCreateDate`. Is that all correct? Or am I overcomplicating things?

Edit:
If I wasn't clear, I want to set creation date metadata on mp4 files using its filename that contains the date, so that programs can sort all my media files by their metadata

Comment: Please explain plainly what you want to accomplish. Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Your question was clear. And 20190228 was my birthday! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses *ffmpeg* (`sudo apt install ffmpeg` to install) and works on your exact file names. It replaces your old files with new ones with the metadata set. Maybe try WITHOUT the `&& mv "~$f" "$f"` part first:

```
$ for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -metadata creation_time="${f:0:4}-${f:4:2}-${f:6:2} ${f:9:2}:${f:11:2}:${f:13:2}" -codec copy "~$f" && mv "~$f" "$f"; done
```

Check metadata with:

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet 20190228_155905.mp4 -print_format json -show_entries stream=index,codec_type:stream_tags=creation_time:format_tags=creation_time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know ffmpeg could edit metadata, awesome

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `exiftool`

In this example first run `touch` to set the file mod time, then:

```
exiftool '-CreateDate<FileModifyDate' \
  '-TrackCreateDate<FileModifyDate' \
  '-MediaCreateDate<FileModifyDate' \
  filename.mp4
```